# MVP and Android Handling Lifecycle events, where to do UI logic

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

I am converting my application to use the MVP pattern. There is some debate between the developers on the proper use of MVP especially in regards to the Android lifecycle and where the UI related logic goes. There is no debate that any hard logic should be done in the presenter, and that the network

---

In the case I need to do Anything for lifecycle functions, onresume, onPause, etc. Should I ...

1. Call a mPresenter.onResumeEvent(); The presenter then does calls. IE
   contract.restoreState(); contract.connectToService() etc.

**or**

2. Do all the logic I need here and not involve the controller. IE
   restoreState, start up loading spinners, etc.

I view it as onResume is an event. All events should be processed by the Presenter. The counter arguments is, we do not want to write code that "ping pongs," I.E. OnResume -> Presenter -> one line function that shows a spinner (or something close to that effect)

---

Now a bit more granule.
Lets says I start my activity, and I need to show either an error or the data depending if the data is null.

I could either do..

```
(presenter)
contract.setupUi(data);
```

then

```
(view)
setupUi(Object data){
if(data != null){
//show data 
}
else{
//show error
}
```

Which has the UI controlling the state evoked from the presenter.

Or I could do

```
(presenter)
if(data != null){
contract.showUI(data);
}
else{
contract.showError();
}
```

Which has the contract looking at all the states.

---

Is the over all goal to have the Presenter Completely control everything about the application and treat the view as completely Dumb. Or is it just dividing up the code purely for testing purposes. Or is it both?

---

**Recap.**

1. How should I handle the lifecycle -- treat it as an event or let the
   view just do it.
2. Where should the view related logic go? Let the Presenter figure out
   what is null and what UI to show. Or let the view take care of it?
3. What should my over all focus be? Controlling the app with the
   presenter, unit testing, both?

Answer (score 1):

Very good questions, but, unfortunately, they do not have definitive answers.

It boils down to the fact that MVP (or any other MVx) is not a specific implementation, but rather a high level architectural pattern which is subject to interpretation.

Said that, my answers to your questions:

1. I'm a strong believer that UI logic doesn't belong into Activity/Fragment at all, therefore MVx views should never be aware of lifecycle events.
2. UI logic goes into standalone class that takes on responsibility of MVx view. Where you put null checks depend on the purpose of this check: if the result only affects UI (e.g. show/hide UI element) then perform the check in MVx view; if the result affects application's flow (e.g. show prompt dialog, change screen, etc.) then perform the check in the presenter; if both - perform checks in both presenter and view
3. Your overall focus should be on writing a maintainable code. Maintainable, first and foremost, means readable.

Again - the above answers are IMHO.

You might also be interested in this series of posts that I wrote: [MVP and MVC Architectures in Android](http://www.techyourchance.com/mvp-mvc-android-1/)